# how to redirect through user-home page

Tags: php

I am trying to redirect the index page to `user-home.php` page. but when I am trying to login its showing wrong user. How to redirect to the user-home page by this condition. expecting help. Thanks in advance. The following image is the database property of the signup page.

[database of signup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNZhf.png)

**HERE IS MY CODE FOR INDEX PAGE**

```
<form  method="post" action="" autocomplete="on">
    <h3>Log in</h3>
    <hr>
    <p>
        <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" > Your username </label>
        <input id="username" name="username" required="required" type="text"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p"> Your password </label>
        <input id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password"/>
    </p>
    <p class="login button">
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
    </p>

</form>
<h2>dont have an account signup here</h2>
<li><a href="signup-form.php">signup</a></li>





</table>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $q=$db->prepare("SELECT* FROM signup WHERE username='$username' && password='$password'" );
    $q->execute();
    $row=$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $count = $q->rowcount();

    if ($count >= 1){    
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['user_id'];
        header('location:user-home.php');
    }else{
        echo "<script>alert ('Wrong User')</script>";
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Are you storing passwords in *plain text*???

Comment: Can you please add this line of code print_r($count); and show me out put of it?

Comment: And using prepared statements but injecting the (unsanitised) user input directly?

Comment: What tutorial did you follow to learn such bad practices?

Comment: Also you're fetching an object (`PDO::FETCH_OBJ`) and then accessing it as an array (`$row['user_id']`) and then you wonder why you get the "cannot use object of type stdClass as array" error you mention in comments on an answer...